# Is it possible to build a process with a work type like test case in azure dev ops

Tags: azure-devops

Good day all,

I am trying to build a custom work item type in azure dev ops. i really like the functionality of the test case steps feature. Its a table, with simple navigation and CRUD operations. However, when you go to inspect how test cases builds this feature, all it says is "Textbox (multiple lines)". Which isn't the case.

Does anyone know if it is possible, or if there is an extension to add tables as a field to a work item type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to customize a work item field like the "steps" field of the test case , I am afraid this demand is not feasible. I also tried to add a field by using an existing field (Steps),but this not works,the actual field still displays like text.

The Steps field is used to support Test case management. So I think this field is specific to the test case. For details ,you can refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/work-item-field?view=azure-devops).
[image]

You could also submit a suggestion ticket to suggest the new feature through this [url](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21).

Comment: Thank you, i had a feeling this was the case. I'll create a suggestion ticket for creating customizable CRUD tables as a field.